# Директору или инспектору: единственное или множественное число?

Tags: грамматика

> Директору или инспектору нужно быть особенно внимательным(и).

Если бы было вместо "или" - "и", то вопросов бы не возникало. А как быть в такой ситуации?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь единственное число. Именно потому, что "или". То есть предполагается, что будет либо тот, либо другое — то есть, кто-то один.